# Finding the sine of X without the use of a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve the following equation using trigonometric identities without the use of a calculator. In order to find the solution, I used the double angle trigonometric identity.Unfortunately, it seems I have made a mistake in my calculation and I cannot seem to find it.

I want to find $sin(\dfrac{-7\pi}{12})$.

I know from the double angle trigonometric identity that
$$sin\left(\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{-7\pi}{6}\right)}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-cos\left(\dfrac{-7\pi}{6}\right)}{2}}$$

$$sin(\dfrac{-7\pi}{12})=\sqrt{\dfrac{1--\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2}}$$
$$sin(\dfrac{-7\pi}{12})=\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}}$$
$$sin(\dfrac{-7\pi}{12})=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$

Looking online for a simplifier I get a different answer... What went wrong?

Comment: I've heard of the identity $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$, but frankly it's the first time I ever read of $\sin \frac x2=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$. That doesn't look like a thing at all!

Comment: The half angle formula is $sin^2(a)=\dfrac{1-cos2a}{2}$ If you take the square root on both side and replace $a$ with $\dfrac{b}{2}$ assuming $a=\dfrac{b}{2}$ you get what I used

Comment: If you take the square root of both side you obtain $\lvert \sin a\rvert=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2a)}2}$, which doesn't look like what you used.

Comment: If $a=b/2$ then $sin(b/2)=\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1-cosb}{2}}$

Comment: Ah, so indeed the identity *wasn't* a thing.

Comment: It is a formula derived from the half angle formula, it solved my problem with the answer below. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: It's fine. Personally, I don't like the $\pm$ notation unless it means "either works": when it means "just one works, but I can't be bothered explaining which", it's a formula that does half its work, and work is not like strawberries.  But I mean, if people like it, the more for them the better.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ compared to sin x which gives $sin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for your signs when using $$sin\left(\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{-7\pi}{6}\right)}{2}\right)= \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1-cos\left(\dfrac{-7\pi}{6}\right)}{2}}$$

You may have a negative solution as well.

Comment: Okay I see now that the correct answer had the negative sign. Is it related to the fact that $sin\dfrac{-7\pi}{12}$ is in the third quadrant?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason for the negative sign.

Comment: @CedricMartens think about it, $-\pi/2 = -6 \pi/12,$ and $-\pi = -12\pi/12.$ Your angle $-7\pi/12$ is in between. At the same time, $-7\pi/6 + 2\pi = 5\pi/6$ is in the second quadrant, same position as $-7\pi/6$

Answer (score 1):

$-7 \pi/12$ is in the third quadrant, with negative sine and cosine

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

Use $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$

then $\sin\dfrac{7\pi}{12}=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac\pi3\right)=?$